# Integration of simple functions where the sets aren't disjoint

Tags: measure-theory

In the following question. I am working with the following measure space $(X,\Omega, \mu)$. Suppose that we know the fact that if $\{A_j\}$ are disjoint then we have that following integral holds:

$$\int { \phi d \mu } = \Sigma_{k = 1}^n c_k \mu(A_k)$$

Why does it imply that if $\phi = \Sigma_{k = 1}^n c_k \chi_{A_k}$ then $\int { \phi d \mu } = \Sigma_{k = 1}^n c_k \mu(A_k)$ for $A_k$ not necassarily disjoint.

Comment: Divide the $A_k$ in smaller disjont chunks.

Comment: Sure, but how can we construct such chunks explicitly ?

Comment: Intersections $B_1\cap B_2\cap\cdots\cap B_n$ where $B_k = A_k$ or $X\setminus A_k$.

Comment: I don't understand can you explain more ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: consider the collection of all sets of the form $B_1 \cap B_1\cap...\cap B_n$ where $B_i$ is either $A_i$ or its complement. (There are $2^{n}$ such sets but not all of them may be distinct; may of them may be empty!). Prove the following:

This is a pairwise disjoint collection.

Each $A_i$ is a union of some of the sets in this collection. [ For example, if you consider all sets of the form $B_1 \cap B_1\cap...\cap B_n$ where $B_1=A_1$ and, for $i >1$, $B_i$ is either $A_i$ or its complement the the union of these sets is $A_1$. 
 Can you complete the proof now?

Comment: How do we know it is distinct ? I.e for instance we could intersect $A_1 \cap \ldots \cap A_m \bigcap A_1$ then this would not be pairwise disjoint.

Comment: The sets of the form $B_1\cap B_2\cap... \cap B_n$ are not distinct. May of them may be empty. You have to use the distinct one's from this collection.

Comment: But consider the following:

$B_1 \cap B_2 \cap \ldots B_n \cap B_1$ this is intersection of two distinct collection. This is not pairwise disjoint.

Comment: If you consider any two of these intersections there is at least one $i$ for which $B_i$  in one of them is $A_i$ and, in the other, it is $A_i^{c}$. Hence they are disjoint.

Comment: I don't understand can you be more explicit ?

Comment: For instance $B_1 \cap B_2 \cap \ldots B_n \cap B_1$ isn't disjoint.

Comment: I am unable to see where you  confusion is but I suggest that you take two specific sets $A_1,A_2$ , say intervals, and write down all sets of the form $B_1 \cap B_2$.